# How to access a child datagrid which is inside of another datagrid, before it's not binded

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a nested datagrid. I want to get header texts of child datagrid, bifore binding process.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook into the [`ItemDataBound` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.itemdatabound.aspx). In here, you can `FindControl()` for your nested DataGrid and bind that on the fly.

```
protected void DataGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid child = e.Item.FindControl("theNestedGrid") as DataGrid;
    if(child != null)
    {
         // Binding logic here
    }
}
```